# After updating the query-string library, test:ci now fails

Tags: reactjs, next.js, query-string

The development environment uses next.js 13.
After updating the query-string library to 8.1, test:ci now fails.
It fails at the following point.
**before** "query-string": "^7.1.0",
**after** "query-string": "^8.1.0",

error

```
   ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import * as queryString from './base.js';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.
```

Changed part.
before

```
import { stringifyUrl } from 'query-string';
.
. omission
.
stringifyUrl({url})
```

after

```
import queryString from 'query-string';
.
.　omission
.
 queryString.stringifyUrl({ url })
```

I am very troubled.
If anyone knows how to solve this problem, please let me know.

added

```
module.exports = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
  collectCoverageFrom: ['src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', '!**/*.d.ts'],
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    // Handle CSS imports (with CSS modules)
    // https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack#mocking-css-modules
    '^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',

    // Handle CSS imports (without CSS modules)
    '^.+\\.(css|sass|scss)$': '<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/styleMock.ts',

    // Handle image imports
    // https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack#handling-static-assets
    '^.+\\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp|avif|ico|bmp|svg)$/i': `<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/fileMock.ts`,
    // Handle ESM packages
    '^react-markdown$': '<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/react-markdown.tsx',
  },

  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/', '<rootDir>/.next/'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  transform: {
    // Use babel-jest to transpile tests with the next/babel preset
    // https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transform-objectstring-pathtotransformer--pathtotransformer-object
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$': ['babel-jest', { presets: ['next/babel'] }],
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/',
    '^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$',
  ],
};
```

Comment: Don't [repost](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75379985/3001761). When a major version breaks things, which shouldn't be surprising, **read the docs**.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is `query-string` version 8 introduced a breaking to consuming applications because their dependencies upgraded to ESM. See their release notes [here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string/releases/tag/v8.0.0):

> #### v8.0.0
>
> **Breaking**
>
> - Require Node.js 14
> - This package is now pure ESM. **Please [read this](https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c).**
>
>   - Add [`"module": "node16"`, `"moduleResolution": "node16"`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module) to your
>     `tsconfig.json`.
>     ([Example](https://github.com/sindresorhus/tsconfig/blob/main/tsconfig.json))
>   - [And more!!!](https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c)

It appears Jest in trying to use `import` but it's not configured to do so. Jest also provides some guidance for how to deal with this: https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules

**Since you're using Next.js, those steps don't really apply.**

I'm reproducing and testing in a sandbox... Will update shorty.

**For React apps:**

Try setting `"type": "module"` inside `package.json`.

You should also update your `package.json` test script to:

`"test": "node --experimental-vm-modules ./node_modules/.bin/jest"`

Now inside `jest.config.js` you'll want to export `transform: {}`:

```js
export default {
  transform: {}
}
```

After all those steps, you should no longer have this issue.

Comment: thank you!!
export default {
  transform: {}
}
Where should I put the above code?

Comment: Inside jest.config.js

Comment: I modified test in packege.json and added export default in jest.config.js but when I run the npm run test:ci command I get an error.

Comment: error SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Comment: What version of Jest are you running?

Comment: "jest": "^29.4.2",

Comment: I apologize, the steps I repeated from `query-string` only apply to `React` apps, not `Next.js` apps. I was able to repeat your exact error in a sandbox though - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/next-js-13-jest-tests-96rn09 - I will update you once I find the culprit!

Comment: Facing same issue in next js , Do you find any solution ?